# how to configure SNMP services on F5 server

Tags: snmp, f5, snmpd

Need instructions on how i can install and configure SNMPD service on the logical F5s servers.

on RHEL servers, I can update /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf file and restart the snmpd process with command # service snmpd restart.

but in my F5 server i can't find /etc/snmp/ directory and snmpd does not appear to be a valid service.  Kindly provide steps for updating the snmp.conf file and how to restart the process on F5 node.

Answer (score 1):

snmpd is a service that already exists on the F5 device, it just needs to be configured. This is done via the gui or cli with tmsh, not direct edit of the snmp config file.

[GUI steps](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip_tmos_implementations_11_0_0/15.html)

CLI assistance - *tmsh help /sys snmp*